# Is taking the address of a local variable a constant expression in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, pointer-arithmetic

The following C++11 program:

```
int x = 42;

void f()
{
        int y = 43;

        static_assert(&x < &y, "foo");
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

Doesn't compile with gcc 4.7 as it complains:

```
error: ‘&y’ is not a constant expression
```

This would agree with my intuition.  The address of `y` potentially changes with each invocation of `f`, so of course it cannot be calculated during translation.

However none of the bullet points in 5.19 [expr.const] seem to preclude it from being a constant expression.

The only two contenders I see are:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion...

but unless I am mistaken (?) there are no lvalue-to-rvalue conversions in the program.

And

> an `id-expression` that refers to a variable [snip] unless:
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression

which `y` is - it is initialized with the constant expression `43`.

So is this an error in the standard, or am I missing something?

**Update:**

It's confusing as hell, but I think I am on top of it, so let me show an example that will show off what is going on:

```
int x = 42;

void f()
{
        int y = 43;

        // address constant expressions:    
        constexpr int* px = &x; // OK
        constexpr int* py = &y; // ERROR: pointer context for local variable

        // boolean constant expressions:
        constexpr bool bx = &x; // OK
        constexpr bool by = &y; // OK

        // comparison constant expressions:
        constexpr bool eq = (&x == &y); // OK
        constexpr bool lt = (&x < &y); // ERROR: undefined behaviour disqualifies 
                                                 a constant expression
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

First distinguish between a core constant expression (5.19p2) and a constant expression (5.19p4).  Specifcally sub-expressions of a constant expression only have to be core constant expressions, not constant expressions.  That is, being a constant expression is a property of the full expression, not sub-expressions.  It further requires to look at the context it which the full expression is used.

So, as it turns out the gcc error is misleading.  Firstly `&y` may be a constant expression in some contexts.  Secondly, the reason `&x < &y` isn't a constant expression is because of the comparison of unrelated pointers, not of the sub-expression `&y`.

Comment: Any operation using unrelated pointers are undefined, if I remember correctly. Thus comparing the address of one variable to the address of another will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Undefined in C; unspecified in C++.

Comment: "An *address
constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of pointer type that evaluates to the **address of an
object with static storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer value**, or a prvalue core
constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t.`"

Comment: @JoachimPileborg only `<` and friends are unspecified, `!=` works fine, see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try to determine which requirements the expression in the *static_assert-declaration* has to fulfil step-by-step, using n3485.

[dcl.dcl]/1

> *static_assert-declaration:*
>       `static_assert (`*constant-expression*`,`*string-literal*`) ;`

[dcl.dcl]/4

> In a *static_assert-declaration* the *constant-expression* shall be a constant expression that can be contextually converted to `bool`.

[expr.const]/4

> Collectively, *literal constant expressions*, *reference constant expressions*, and *address constant expressions* are called *constant expressions*.

---

So what type of constant expression is `&x < &y`? It is **not** an *address constant expression*:

[expr.const]/4

> An *address constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression (after conversions as required by the context) of type `std::nullptr_t` or of pointer type [...].

The type of `&x < &y` is `bool` as per [expr.rel]/1.

It isn't a *reference constant expression* either, so it must be a *literal constant expression*, **if any**.

> A *literal constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type [...]

Therefore, `&x < &y` has to fulfil the requirements of a *core constant expression*.

---

As [pointed out by TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352680/420683) and [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) in the comments, in this particular case, `&x < &y` does not fulfil the requirements of a *core constant expression*:

[expr.const]/2

> [a core constant expression must not contain] a relational or equality operator where the result is unspecified;

[expr.rel]/2

> If two pointers `p` and `q` of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results of `p<q`, `p>q`, `p<=q`, and `p>=q` are unspecified.

However, for an example like

```
int arr[2] = {1, 2};
static_assert(&a[0] < &a[1], "");
```

The expression `a < a+1` fulfils this requirement as well.

Comment: `&x < &y` is not a core constant expression, because is contains "a relational (5.9) or equality (5.10) operator where the result is unspecified". It is therefore not a literal constant expression either.

Comment: @hvd Yes (*in this case* it's not a core c.e.), all I stated is that *it must fulfil the requirements of a core constant expression*. I'll try to point that out.

Comment: Your answer is correct, and the final example is well-formed, even if `arr` is a local variable, and gcc accepts it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you're missing the fact that, while `y` itself is initialised with a constant expression, that's *not* the same as `&y`.

The address of `y` can vary a great deal depending on your call stack history.

Paragraph 3 of `C++11 5.19 Constant expressions` states the conditions under which the address-of operator can be considered a constant expression (how core constant expressions detailed in paragraph 2 are allowed to morph into "real" constant expressions):

> ... An address constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of pointer type that evaluates to **the address of an object with static storage duration,** to **the address of a function,** or to a **null pointer value,** or a **prvalue core constant expression of type std::nullptr_t.** Collectively, literal constant expressions, reference constant expressions, and address constant expressions are called constant expressions.

Since `&y` is none of those things, it's not considered a constant expression.

Comment: So you're saying that `&y` is not a constant expression?  Which bullet point in 5.19 precludes it from being so?

Comment: What makes you think it migt be?

Comment: Because it is a `conditional-expression`, and all `conditional-expressions` are constant expressions unless they involve one of the subexpressions listed in 5.19

Comment: @user1131467 No, such `conditional-expressions` are *core constant expressions.* They only become *constant expressions* by conforming to one of the rules in 5.19p3.

Comment: @Angew That's not a comment - it's an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the passage I was looking for, but couldn't find.  (I know where it is in pre-C++11.)

Comment: It turns out that address constant expressions are a red-herring in this case.  `static_assert(&x < &y)` is ill-formed because it causes undefined behaviour (comparing two unrelated pointers), therefore it is not a core constant expression.  Both `static_assert(&y)` and `static_assert(&x == &y)` are well-formed and are constant expressions in a bool context.

Comment: @user1131467 Unspecified behavior, not undefined.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Correct, sorry.  The relevant bullet point is "a core constant expression shall not contain a relational (5.9) or equality (5.10) operator where the result is unspecified"

Answer (score 5):

Taking the address of something is not the culprit here, but rather the pointer comparison using `operator<` on unrelated objects.

Relational operators on pointers is only specified for pointers to objects within the same class or within an array (5.9 Relational operators [expr.rel], points 3 and 4.) **Relational comparison for pointers to unrelated objects is unspecified.**

Comparing the address for **equality** rather than **ordering** does work:

```
int x = 42;

void f()
{
        int y = 43;

        static_assert(&x != &y, "foo");
                         ^^ <--- "<" on unrelated objects is unspecified
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6abc2127ed22884a374317aa7f334f1a-7fa5748cb8ba984550f021f5e689240a)

Just to show that this has nothing to do with const-expressions per se,

```
void f()
{
        int y[2] = { 42, 43 };

        static_assert(&y[0] < &y[1], "foo");
                            ^ <--- "<" on objects within an array is specified
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

Another [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=482a8061502961a9e1e31acfc39f9d4f-6b864d01527066fb211cc4a5466784d9).

Comment: It shouldn't work in a `static_assert`, since in this case, it's not a constant expression, since `&y` isn't a constant expression.

Comment: @JamesKanze works on clang and g++. I think that passing an unspecified result to `static_assert` is the culprit, not the constness of &y.

Comment: Then the compilers have an error. "In a static_assert-declaration
the constant-expression shall be a constant expression[...]"
(§7.4) and "An address constant expression is a prvalue core constant
expression of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an
object with static storage duration, to the address of
a function, or to a null pointer value, or a prvalue core
constant expression of type std::nullptr_t." (§5.19/3).

Comment: @JamesKanze should I file bug reports then?

Comment: @JamesKanze A question poses itself: Can a constant expression be formed out of subexpressions that are not constant expressions themselves? Does the standard prohibit this explicitly? I think `&x != &y` can be reliably true at compile time, since two distinct objects can't have same address. The actual values of pointers are irrelevant for value of that expression, no?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Incorrect. :)  gcc is right.  It is confusing as hell I grant you.  A constant expression does not have to have constant expressions as sub-expressions.  It only has to have core constant expressions as sub-expressions.  Furthermore the context in which the full expression is evaluated effects whether a core constant expression is a constant expression.  `static_assert(&x < &y)` in my example fails because it causes undefined behaviour, and `&x < &y` is therefore not a core constant expression.  It has nothing to do with address constant expressions.  This will take time to digest

Comment: Notice that `static_assert(&y)` is also ok, because `&y` in a bool context is a constant expression. :)

Comment: @user1131467 yes I noticed that

Comment: @TemplateRex Probably, if there isn't one already.  (When using C++11 features, you should probably expect bugs, since they are recent additions to the compiler.)

Comment: @user1131467 In other words, `a + b` is a constant expression,
even if `a` and `b` aren't.  You might read the last sentence
of §5.19/3 as well.  A constant expression must be a literal
constant expression, a reference constant expression or a an
address constant expression.  (But the entire section needs
rewriting.)

Comment: @user1131467 On rereading the section (for the third time): you may be right.  `&x != &y` is a literal expression of integral type (since `bool` is an integral type). And `x != y` is banned because it involves an lvalue to rvalue conversion (which is not one of those listed as exceptions).  In general, it doesn't make sense that a constant expression can involve things which aren't constants (even if in this case, it is determinable), but that's what it looks like.

Comment: And of course, this is a change with regards to earlier versions.  In pre-C++11, something like `int a[&x != &y];` was illegal.  IIUC, in C++11, it is now legal.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes `a + b` contains two lvalue-to-rvalue conversions, so only qualifies as a core constant expression if the relevant bullet points in 5.19p2 fit.  Roughly that `a` and `b` are non-volatile const, and by the `id-expression` requirement that they are initialized with constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I agree that the previous answer was probably an incorrect reading of the items. Instead, the actual relevant clause is 5.19 [expr.const] paragraph 3 which reads (highlightening added):

> A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, **but not pointer type**. An
>   integral constant expression is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. [ Note:
>   Such expressions may be used as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers
>   if the underlying type is not fixed (7.2), as null pointer constants (4.10), and as alignments (7.6.2). —end
>   note ] A converted constant expression of type T is a literal constant expression, implicitly converted to type T,
>   where the implicit conversion (if any) is permitted in a literal constant expression and the implicit conversion
>   sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5),
>   and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4). [ Note: such expressions may be used
>   as case expressions (6.4.2), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), and as integral or
>   enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3). —end note ] A reference constant expression is an lvalue
>   core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function. **An address
>   constant expression** is a prvalue core constant expression of pointer type that evaluates to the **address of an
>   object with static storage duration**, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer value, or a prvalue core
>   constant expression of type std::nullptr_t. **Collectively, literal constant expressions, reference constant
>   expressions, and address constant expressions are called constant expressions.**

A core constant expression isn't directly a constant expression, there are additional conditions which are spelled out in this third paragraph.

Comment: But if you read it that way then what precludes an expression of `i` from being a constant expression after a declaration of `const int i = 42;`.  Under your reading `i` is not a constant expression.  I think you are parsing the prose wrong, the sub-bullet conditions are for both all variables and some references.

Comment: No, I don't think that's how you're supposed to read it. After `extern int a;`, `&a` is a perfectly valid constant, and by your interpretation, it isn't.

Comment: I don't see a _reference type_ in the question?

Comment: @MSalters The interpretation in this answer is: "variable", or "data member of reference type". Since the question has a variable, not a data member, it doesn't matter whether it's of reference type. (Again, I don't think the interpretation is correct.)

Comment: Probably this list item should be split in two, so the _"unless the reference"..._ clause appears only in the "data member" case where it applies

Answer (score 1):

5.19p2 does not define *constant expressions,* it defines *core constant expressions.*

A *core constant expression* only becomes a *constant expression* if it conforms to one of the rules in 5.19p3. There, the relevant part was already pointed out by jrok:

> An *address constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with static storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer value, or a prvalue core constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Your core constant expression `&y` does not evaluate to any of those, so it's not an *address constant expression,* and thus not a *constant expression.*

Comment: The `static_assert` declaration requires a "constant expression that can be contextually converted to `bool`" [dcl.dcl]/4. Although a "constant expression" is either a *literal c.e.*, *reference c.e.* or *address c.e.* [expr.const]/4, the expression `&x < &y` is *not* an *address constant expression* itself (it's neither of pointer type nor of `nullptr_t`). It must be a *literal c.e.*, and can therefore contain *core c.e.*. Using n3485

Comment: @DyP Good point. In other words, the problem here is only the `<`? Interesting indeed.

Comment: Well whether or not the `<` is the only problem is another question, but I think the answer to that is *yes*.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ pre-C++11:

> Other expressions [than integral constant expressions] are
>   considered constantexpressions only for the purpose of
>   nonlocal static object initialization (3.6.2).  Such
>   constant expressions shall evaluate to one of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> -- an address constant expression,
>
> [...]
>
> An address constant expression is a pointer to an lvalue
>   designating an object of static storage duration, a string
>   literal (2.13.4), or a function.

Since `y` doesn't have static storage duration, `&y` would not
be a constant expression.

C++11 seems to have changed this; I suspect that this is an
oversignt, however.  (C++ pre-C++11 lists the things that are
constant expressions.  C++11 lists the things that aren't.  It
would be easy for one to have been forgotten.)

Regardless, of course: your comparison isn't usable in standard
C++; the results of comparing two addresses which don't point
into the same object is unspecified.  (On the other hand, I have
occasionally used something similar in machine dependent code.
Not statically, but on platforms like Linux on PC or Solaris,
it's possible to determine whether a pointer points to an object
with static lifetime, and auto variable, or dynamically
allocated memory with such tricks.)

### EDIT:

The answser by paxdiablo has quoted the passage I didn't find in
my reading of C++11; C++11 follows the same rule as C++ pre-11
in this respect, and in order to be a constant address
expression, the address must be that of an object with static
lifetime (or a function, or a null pointer).