# G++ vs Clang : inconsistent behavior for constexpr and const

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, static-assert

Consider the following code:

```
constexpr const int A = 42;

const int &B = A;
static_assert(&A == &B, "Bug");

constexpr const int &C = B;
static_assert(&A == &C, "Bug");

int main() { return 0; }
```

It is perfectly accepted by clang version 3.3, whereas g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388 refuses it with:

```
bug2.cpp:5:1: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
 static_assert(&A == &B, "Bug");
 ^
bug2.cpp:5:1: error: the value of ‘B’ is not usable in a constant expression
bug2.cpp:2:12: note: ‘B’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
 const int &B = A;
            ^
```

It seems to me that GCC is correct (whereas I certainly would prefer clang behavior). Trying to read the standard I realized that I'm not enough of a language lawyer to decide. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: clang 3.5 generates an error on this code, [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d83b4749715ad239).

Comment: The clang project evolves very fast, 3.3 is already outdated.

Comment: Do you actually want to *use* such code somewhere? Just wondering.

Comment: Not as such of course. If you want some background see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178366/array-of-class-element-as-a-static-constexpr-member

Comment: Changing `A` to static makes this work for the first case, the standard is a little vague on this, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: FYI this might have something to do with the change of rules for `constexpr` expressions between C++11 and C++14; C++14 introduced relaxed rules for `constexpr` expressions, which allow to *mutate* state in a `constexpr` function, and as a result `constexpr` in C++14 does not imply `const` (despite the name, which is awkward).

Comment: @MatthieuM. the closest I can find in the draft C++11 standard is this: `A reference constant expression is an lvalue
core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function.` from `5.19 p 4` It does not tell much more than that but seems consistent with my previous observation.

Comment: clang accepts your updated code but `gcc` does not, this looks like a a `gcc` bug to me and that makes more sense too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the value of ‘B’ is not usable in a constant expression` is incorrect. You are not performing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on B, which is the usual meaning of "value;" you are only taking its address. The only relevant constant-expression rule forbids:

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression;

However `B` does have a preceding initialization to a reference constant expression.

> A *reference constant expression* is an lvalue core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function.

In this case, `B`'s initializer is `A`, which is as constant as you can get. `A` and `B` statically refer to the same object.

So, this is a GCC bug.

Answer (score 1):

Without being a language lawyer, you cannot use a reference as a constant expression in general, only values (if there are exceptions please correct me). In this sense, the closest valid to your code would be:

```
constexpr int A = 42;
constexpr int B = A;

static_assert(A == B, "Bug");
```

However, in my case, both Clang 3.3 and GCC 4.8.1 give errors on your code as expected.

**EDIT** Apparently my knowledge is still a bit narrow, sorry. There are probably exceptions depending on linkage, for instance the code is accepted ([live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07d19a1654379dc)) if the statements are global, outside `main()`.

Comment: I don't think you are right. Just add `constexpr` to the line `const int &B = A;` and my code seems to be correct.

Comment: @hivert See [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ec66a890bc628fd) - am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know. This is completely different that my computer behavior.

Comment: @hivert See my edit, code compiles when statements are global, which you did not specify in your question.

Comment: @iavr yes that would make them static, which I commented on in the question.

Comment: @iavr : I didn't realize: Of course the address of a *local* variable can't be computed at compile time.

Comment: @hivert Which doesn't mean that you can't use them in a constant expression: `&a == &b` where `a` and `b` are local objects is a core constant expression.

Comment: @jrok : How is this possible ? If a is a local variable `&a` is only know when you launch the function.

Comment: @hivert Intuitively, because addresses of two distinct objects cannot be equal and we know that at compile time. But see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352385/is-taking-the-address-of-a-local-variable-a-constant-expression-in-c11) for a standardese discussion.