# Comparison of pointers to static constexpr variables in a constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

In the following code, pointers to `static constexpr` variables `x` and `y` are compared for not-equality:

```
int main() {
    static constexpr int x = 1;
    static constexpr int y = 2;
    static_assert( &x != &y );
}
```

It works fine in Clang, but not in GCC which prints

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
error: '((& x) != (& y))' is not a constant expression
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3WdqP49Gq

Is it just a bug in GCC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is taking the address of a local variable a constant expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352385/is-taking-the-address-of-a-local-variable-a-constant-expression-in-c11)

Comment: @francesco, your question is about less-more comparison of unrelated object pointers, and there is no different behavior of compilers there as far as I can see. But thanks for the link anyway,

Comment: GCC bug? [Yes](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85428).